# XCTest & GPX Files: Can Location Updates Be Started Automatically?

Tags: xcode9, xctest, gpx

I have added a gpx file to my project; its name is TrailOfHistory.gpx. I have edited my project's scheme so that this file will be used by Xcode 9 to perform locations updates.

Here are screen shots of the scheme's Run and Test configurations wherein I have designated that the gpx file should be used:

[image: Scheme's Run Configuration]

[image: Scheme's Test Configuration]

When I run my application, user location updates (as given by the gpx file) begin automatically. I can watch this happening on my application's MKMapView.

In contrast, when I run one of my unit tests, user location updates do not begin automatically. I must instead perform the manual step of clicking the debug toolbar's Simulate Location button and choosing the gpx file; as shown in the following screen shot:

[image: Debug Toolbar's Simulate Location Menu]

My ultimate goal is to arrive at a set of tests that can be executed by a continuous integration system. So, clicking on Xcode buttons is not going to fly.

Can anyone provide insight on this? In particular, can anyone say that he/she has had the experience of creating an XCTest wherein location updates began automatically (if so then I'll proceed with hope; currently I am unclear what expectations I should have)?

Note: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471978/xcode-scheme-default-location-is-ignored-in-tests) very similar question, over a year old. Hopefully I can generate some renewed interest.

Comment: Did you finally find a solution @Verticon ?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this working using the following approach;

1. Go to the relevant scheme and select 'Edit Scheme...'

[image]

2. Select the 'Tests' for that scheme on the left hand side, and then click the 'Options' button for the UnitTest target.

[image]

3. Set the 'Location' variable to your GPX trail.

[image]

These steps are allowing me to test my CoreLocation functions as expected.

I feel like these options may have not been available when this question was written, but just incase this helps people with this issue going forwards I thought I would answer here.